# Check if SQL Server is reachable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I would like to log in to a SQL Server instance (`MSSQLSERVER`) and to a particular database (`DB1`). How can I do that with Delphi? A nice way that would cover the exceptions and sensible warning messages?

Edit: I would like to see an working example on how to go about that.

Edit2: I tried this way, but I wonder if this is OK

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 UNIConnection1.Server := 'MSSQLSERVER';
 UNIConnection1.ProviderName := 'SQL Server';
 UNIConnection1.Username := 'username';
 UNIConnection1.Password := 'password';
 UNIConnection1.Database := 'DB1';
 UNIConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
 try
 UNIConnection1.Connect;
 StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Server is running.';
 except
  on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Server is not reachable');
end;
end;
```

Comment: You can use [`Ping`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Ping) to check whether the DBMS is alive (if that's what you're asking for). [I'm not voting down, just to close since this question lacks the sense]

Comment: What do you mean "it lacks sense" ? Also,as far as I know,there is no need for a ping since the connection either opens or fails.

Comment: You just try to connect to that server and that database - and be prepared to handle a failure. If that server isn't there, if the database is unavailable, if your login credentials are wrong - all could lead to a failure, so you need to be ready to handle those

Comment: So, are you asking how to handle errors when attempting to login to a DBMS ? If so, [`start here`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Establishing_Connection_(FireDAC)#Handling_Connection_Errors) (assuming FireDAC looking at your previous questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ? :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (button1.Caption='Connect') then
 begin
 UNIConnection1.Server := 'MSSQLSERVER';
 UNIConnection1.ProviderName := 'SQL Server';
 UNIConnection1.Username := 'username';
 UNIConnection1.Password := 'password';
 UNIConnection1.Database := 'DB1';
 UNIConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
 try
 UNIConnection1.Connect;
 StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Server is running.';
 Button1.Caption:='Disconnect';
 except
  on E: Exception do
  StatusBar1.Simpletext := 'Connection error: '+e.message; 
  end;
 end else
 if (button1.Caption='Disconnect')   then
  begin
    UNIConnection1.Disconnect;
    Button1.Caption:='Connect';
    StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Server is not running.';
  end;
  end;
```

you can also add this :

```
procedure TForm1.UniConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Waiting for connection.....';
end;
```

Also you should consider adding a timeout to the connection:

> UniConnection.SpecificOptions.Values['ConnectionTimeout'] := '60';

edit: I have changed the code and added Johns suggestion for the error message....

Comment: Would like to see this handle all the various exceptions that could occur.  A lazy response of  'Server is not running' isn't enough..the original also asks about a particular db instance exists, and also asks for sensible warning messages.. this doesn't do any of that.  Even though it is the accepted answer..

Comment: @ John Easley - Anything wrong with the connection (that includes nonexistent database or whatever) and the connection will throw an exception. Basic.To cover them all (by name) is another matter...way too long....But this is all hardcoded so I assume he knows the instance since it is provided by code.

Comment: Raising the original exception is better, which would provide at least the correct error text. But handling all potential exceptions  as a 'Server is not running' is bad, imo. I would at a minimum modify the exception text to include the actual exception, example: StatusBar1.Simpletext := 'Connection error: '+e.message; -- make sense?

Comment: Agree John...Changed the line....

Answer (score -1):

Let windows do the work. You can create an "udl" file and open it from the win explorer by double click or from your program with e.g. shellexecute. It comes up with a configuration dialog and it has on the second page a "test connection" Button.